# Law of $\max_t(\int_0^tb(\omega,s)\,dB_s-\int_0^tb(\omega,s)^2\,ds)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a continuous process given by
$$
X_t:=\int_0^tb(\omega,s)\,dB_s-\int_0^tb(\omega,s)^2\,ds
$$
where $b\in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$ such that $\int_0^tb^2\,ds\to\infty$ with probability one.
Then, I want to find the law of $\sup_{t\geq 0}X_t$.

I don't know how to start with this problem. I tried consider a simpler case where $X_t = B_t - t$, but I still don't know what to do. I think this has something to do with that we can write $X_t = M_t - \langle M\rangle_t$ where $M_t$ is a local martingale.
I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Without knowing the law of $b(\,.\,,s)$ I don't think that this has a solution. Where does that problem come from?

Comment: It's in the material of a course I'm taking. I couldn't find where this was referenced from.